# MySQL LIKE x || y || z || etc. stops working after first ||

Tags: mysql, sql

Query looks like:

```
SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%bla%' || '%bla2%' || '%bla3%' AND     last_visit > '2013-05-15 00:00:00'");
```

The query only fetches the records that contain "bla" or "bla2", skipping bla3.

How come?

Comment: Ps.: I tried LIKE bla || LIKE bla2 || LIKE bla3, doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are performing a logical OR on strings, this is not what you intend.

You need to write it like this:

```
SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE (username LIKE '%bla%' or username like '%bla2%' or username like '%bla3%') AND last_visit > '2013-05-15 00:00:00'";
```

**Edit:** Updated to include the correction in Goat CO's answer

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to apply `last_visit > '2013-05-15 00:00:00'"` to all records you'll need parenthesis:

```
SELECT username, email 
FROM users 
WHERE (username LIKE '%bla%' or username like '%bla2%' or username like '%bla3%') 
       AND last_visit > '2013-05-15 00:00:00'";
```

If you use:

```
SELECT username, email 
FROM users 
WHERE username LIKE '%bla%' or username like '%bla2%' or username like '%bla3%'
       AND last_visit > '2013-05-15 00:00:00'";
```

It will return all records like 'bla' or 'bla2', but only 'bla3' after '2013-05-15'.

Comment: Great point, I figured I had this issue after fixing the issue of the main question here.